# How to map DNS entries to ports using Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have a single Ubuntu machine with three services all running on different ports.

- GitLab running on port `80`
- EtherPad running on port `9001`
- GemInABox running on port `9292`.

There are three DNS names pointing to this one Ubuntu server, `gitlab.domain.com`, `etherpad.domain.com`, and `geminabox.domain.com`.

The GitLab service works well with Nginx, no changes needed here. However, I'm not sure how to configure Nginx to allow requests to `etherpad.domain.com` to pass through to `etherpad.domain.com:9091`, and requests to `geminabox.domain.com` to pass through to `geminabox.domain.com:9292`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can use the nginx you have for GitLab and, as @moebius_eye suggests, configure it as a reverse proxy for Etherpad and GemInABox. Also, to incorporate the functionality you wanted to approach via DNS, you could use what in nginx is called Server Blocks (a concept similar to Virtual Hosts on apache).

You would have to modify your nginx configuring file to contain something of the sort of:

```
server{
    server_name etherpad.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9091/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

server{
    server_name geminabox.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9292/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

You could look up documentation about the nginx Proxy module and about Server Blocks to fit that configuration to your needs, but I think the above is the minimum you need.

Finally, I think there is no straight DNS way to do what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks! This was the clue I needed. The only required addition is `listen 80;` just before the `server_name` line.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is the nginx reverse proxy feature.

Read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the specific server app/protocol doesn't support it (in the form of `SRV` records, [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record)), DNS can't be used for this purpose.